# Flutter Bloc pattern: nested api calls in event handler

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am relatively new to Flutter and still trying to get familiar with the Flutter Bloc pattern. I have created an AuthBloc to handle user authentication.
The auth flow is as follows :
#1 - user signs in using credentials (first endpoint is called).
#2 - when signing is successful we have access to user access and refresh tokens.
#3 - fetch user profile using the retrieved access token (second endpoint is called).
#4 - user tokens as well as user profile are saved to the authenticated state.

In my AuthBloc I want to call both mentioned endpoints one after the other when I receive a LoginRequested event. I am getting this unhandled exception :

**emit was called after an event handler completed normally.
This is usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler.
Please make sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers**

Any help is very much appreciated !.

My code :

```
/*auth_event.dart*/
// When the user signing in with login and password this event is called
// and the [AuthRepository] is called to sign in the user
class LoginRequested extends AuthEvent {
  final CredentialsDTO credentials;

  LoginRequested(this.credentials);
}

/*auth_state.dart*/
// When the user is authenticated the state is changed to Authenticated.
class Authenticated extends AuthState {
  final String accessToken;
  final String refreshToken;
  final User? user;

  Authenticated(this.accessToken, this.refreshToken, this.user);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [accessToken, refreshToken, user];
}

/*auth_bloc.dart*/
// On login button press, send the LoginRequested Event to the AuthBloc
// to handle it and emit the Authenticated State if the user is authenticated
    on<LoginRequested>((event, emit) async {
      emit(Loading());
      final response = await loginUseCase!.call(
        LoginParams(
          login: CredentialsModel(
            login: event.credentials.login,
            password: event.credentials.password,
          ),
        ),
      );
      response.fold(
        (failure) {
          emit(
              AuthError(ErrorObject.mapFailureToErrorObject(failure: failure)));
          emit(UnAuthenticated());
        },
        // I am having trouble in this section of the code !
        (success) async {
          final accessToken = success.accessToken;
          final refreshToken = success.refreshToken;
          final response = await fetchProfileUseCase!.call(
            FetchProfileParams(
              token: SociaLoginModel(accessToken: accessToken),
            ),
          );
          response.fold(
            (failure) {
              emit(AuthError(
                  ErrorObject.mapFailureToErrorObject(failure: failure)));
              emit(UnAuthenticated());
            },
            (success) async =>
                emit(Authenticated(accessToken, refreshToken, success.user)),
          );
        },
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve my issue. Here is how I did it:
Instead of directly calling the fetchProfile endpoint inside the LoginRequested Event, I refactored the code like shown below.
The solution is to add a second event to the bloc after the first one is handled, the second event OnProfileRequested will separately handle the second api call and update the AuthState.

```
 on<LoginRequested>(
      (event, emit) async {
        emit(Loading());
        final response = await loginUseCase!.call(
          LoginParams(
            login: CredentialsModel(
              login: event.credentials.login,
              password: event.credentials.password,
            ),
          ),
        );
        response.fold(
          (failure) {
            emit(
              AuthError(
                ErrorObject.mapFailureToErrorObject(failure: failure),
              ),
            );
            emit(
              UnAuthenticated(),
            );
          },
          // On successful signin, send the ProfileRequested Event to the AuthBloc
          // to handle it and emit the Authenticated State
          (success) => add(
            ProfileRequested(
              TokenDTO(
                accessToken: success.accessToken,
                refreshToken: success.refreshToken,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );

on<ProfileRequested>((event, emit) async {
      final accessToken = event.token.accessToken;
      final response = await fetchProfileUseCase!.call(
        FetchProfileParams(
          token: SociaLoginModel(accessToken: accessToken),
        ),
      );
      emit.isDone;
      response.fold((failure) {
        emit(AuthError(ErrorObject.mapFailureToErrorObject(failure: failure)));
        emit(UnAuthenticated());
      }, (success) {
        emit(Authenticated(
            event.token.accessToken, event.token.refreshToken!, success.user));
      });
    });

``
```